# Change created file permissions routinely with powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, file-permissions

I have a certain problem I'm currently unable to figure out myself. My company has a public folder where users (other workers) can create files. The issue is that this folder needs to be configured in a way that users can create files in that folder on a same day: at each evening a script executes making all newly created files on this folder (including all files on subfolders) read-only.
This public folder is located on Windows 10 based machine.

I already managed to get simple Powershell script that is able to set all filed to read-only in current folder:

```
$folderPath = 'C:\TestFolder' 
Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Recurse -File | % { $_.IsReadOnly=$True }`
```

This powershell script runs from admin account and it means after execution of script daily only admin can edit files in folder, but users cannot anymore. On next day Users can create new files, but not edit current ones anymore and the cycle repeats every day: new files will be "locked" as read-only from next day.

Has anyone idea how to implement these kind of file permission in powershell ?

My own idea of an algotirhm for this script:

- Locate all files recursively
- make them read-only
- remove user access to modify any file found
- keep access to users to create new files and view current ones

  Any advice is highly welcome!

Comment: LempsPC .... I have a few questions. So what if the user wants to create a file with the same name of the locked file from the day before? Do you ever purge "previous daily version" files after x days, etc.? Why not just move the files from the source to the archive/read-only location? Why not have correlated dated folders for the files e.g. `\YYYY-MM-DD`? For Windows, Volume Shadow Services does this for you already, why not use for for previous versions? Can you explain why this scenario is needed and help me understand your ultimate goal and any constraints, must-haves, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify only files older than a specific date with powershell like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Recurse -File | 
    Where-Object CreationTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-1) | 
    % { $_.IsReadOnly=$True }
```

Make sure that the file owner property or their permissions change as well, since the owner usually can set permissions back to read/write. You can check in the file explorer UI or with `Get-Acl \\path\to\file.ext`